# LINQ Left Join On Not Equal Rows

Tags: linq, join, inequality

Im trying to display rows which does not exist from the other table using LINQ. can anyone help me?

Here is the sql im using.

```
select * from table1 
left join table2
on 
table1.col1 = table2.col1 
and 
table1.col2 = table2.col2
where
table2.col1 is null and table2.col2 is null
```

Already searched and found some solution. Here is what i did so far.

```
from t1 in table1
where 
!(from t2 in table1
  join t3 in table2 on
  new { t2.col1, t2.col2 } 
  equals 
  new { t3.col1, t3.col2 }
  select t2.PK).Contains(t1.PK)
  select t1
```

The above code works well but im just wondering if that is the only solution i can use? I mean, instead of using JOIN and CONTAINS method, can't we use left join linq directly with a where clause?

Answer (score 9):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
var query = from t1 in table1
            join t2 in table2
            on new { t1.col1, t2.col2} equals { t2.col1, t2.col2 }
            into groups
            where !groups.Any()
            select t1;
```

Here, `groups` is the set of rows in `t2` which match the "current" `t1` - it will be empty if there aren't any groups, which is exactly what you want. The easiest way of checking whether a sequence is empty is to use the `Any` method.